# SQL: Is there a way to do a Mass String Replace in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, replace

I have some data that needs to be rewritten in my db.
I am trying to turn a full url into a relative url. So basically I need to go and change all the occurences of "https://www.website.com/uploads/images/1dhe5d5B56.jpg"
to be more like "uploads/images/1dhe5d5B56.jpg".

I know there is replace() but not sure if i can use that with an update instead of a select. Any ideas?

Comment: you can `REGEXP` for multiple occurances.

Comment: @Shreyas not in SQL Server

Comment: The question is: How do you identify the site part in this string? If you had a site list in a table, then you could do it in SQL. Otherwise do it in the front-end with Regex.

Comment: How many rows are you trying to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace in update. But be careful! If it is just a simple replace like in your question, then:

```
Update [YourTable] 
set [ColumWithUrl] = Replace([ColumWithUrl], 'https://www.website.com/', '')
```

You can also specify which rows to update with `WHERE`. For all urls with this website:

```
Update [YourTable] 
set [ColumWithUrl] = Replace([ColumWithUrl], 'https://www.website.com/', '')
where [ColumWithUrl] like 'https://www.website.com/%'
```

Or only for image urls:

```
Update [YourTable] 
set [ColumWithUrl] = Replace([ColumWithUrl], 'https://www.website.com/', '')
where [ColumWithUrl] like 'https://www.website.com/uploads/images/%'
```

Comment: How do you handle case: `Index: https://www.website.com/index.html Image: https://www.website.com/uploads/images/1dhe5d5B56.jpg`?

Comment: There is no say in the question that it needs to be handled. How do you know that it shuldn't be just `index.html`?

Comment: Awesome @PmDuda this worked perfectly. It was much more simple than I thought I just had bad syntax when I tried. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `REPLACE` with `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tab
SET col = REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'https://www.website.com/uploads/images','|place|')
           ,'|place|', 'uploads/images')
WHERE col LIKE '%https://www.website.com/uploads/images/%';
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WEV9198)**

Standard `Replace([ColumWithUrl], 'https://www.website.com/', '')` could replace too many values like `https://www.website.com/index.html`.

For:

```
Index: https://www.website.com/index.html 
https://www.website.com/uploads/images/1dhe5d5B56.jpg 
and second https://www.website.com/uploads/images/xyz.jpg

=> 
Index: https://www.website.com/index.html 
uploads/images/1dhe5d5B56.jpg 
and second uploads/images/xyz.jpg
```

Comment: This would perform the replace only for one image. It's not a Mass replace.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I edited my answer. Plus it is doable without regexp.

Answer (score 0):

`substring()` from the first `'/'` after the first `'//'`. Use `charindex()` to get their positions.

```
substring(url,
          charindex('/',
                    url,
                    charindex('//',
                              url)
                    + 2),
          len(url)
          -
          charindex('/',
                    url,
                    charindex('//',
                              url)
                    + 2)
          + 1)
```

Or use `replace()` to remove `'http://'` and `'https://'` (if they are only at the beginning, which should be the case for sane URLs) and go for the first `'/'`.

```
substring(replace(replace(url,
                          'http://',
                          ''),
                  'https://',
                  ''),
          charindex('/',
                    replace(replace(url,
                                    'http://',
                                    ''),
                    'https://',
                    '')),
          len(replace(replace(url,
                              'http://',
                              ''),
                      'https://',
                      ''))
          -
          charindex('/',
                    replace(replace(url,
                                    'http://',
                                    ''),
                    'https://',
                    ''))
          +
          1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/31642)

---

Edit:

Hmm, I may have missed, that the URLs might be embedded in other text? That wasn't clear to me from the question. If that is the case my solution is only of partial use of course, if any. Maybe clarify if the URLs are embedded or not.